# How to read/write "binary" files form Hadoop/HDFS using RUBY gem ganapati

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, hadoop, hdfs

I am using the [Ganapati Ruby gem](https://github.com/livingsocial/ganapati) to read/write files from a Hadoop HDFS cluster as pointed out in this question - [How to write and read files in/from Hadoop HDFS using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125519/how-to-write-and-read-files-in-from-hadoop-hdfs-using-ruby)

But this works properly only for text files. How to make it work for binary files (images, pdf, doc, xls, etc)?
I have already edited the client.rb file in the gem code to use the 'b' flag as required by Ruby for binary files in Kernel.open(). The [original gem](https://github.com/livingsocial/ganapati/tree/master/lib/ganapati/client.rb) was not using this flag.
But this still does not help.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you add notes on what the problem _exactly_ is when you attempt to write arbitrary bytes? Does the API not provide such an interface, or do you face other forms of issues such as encoding?

Comment: It seems the API does not provide such an interface. Will rather wait for a new update on this.

Comment: If the ruby binding relies on ``thriftfs``, then I'm afraid it has no life ahead of it, as that component has been shelved away and is no longer shipped with HDFS. The HDFS APIs have moved onto using Protobufs natively now, allowing other forms of clients to pop up in future.